# A tool in QGIS like region group

Tags: qgis, raster

I am trying to find a tool in QGIS that does the same function as Region group in ArcGIS.

What I am trying to do is to identify uniquely each patch of a raster that has a certain value (e.g "Value" =1) using neighbouring cells.

From the [region group docs](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/region-group.htm):

> For each cell in the output, the identity of the connected region to which that cell belongs is recorded. A unique number is assigned to each region.

Answer (score 8):

To get a similar tool to [Region Group](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/region-group.htm), you need to use [r.clump](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.clump.html) in GRASS, which can be accessed from QGIS if you have installed GRASS using OSGeo4W advanced installer.

The tool can be found in`QGIS -> Processing Toolbox -> GRASS Commands -> Raster -> r.clump`

[image]

As a test, I used small portion of land use map with 7 classes, as you can see below:

[image]

After running the tool, the land use map was reclassified into 35 groups (35 unique pixel values) with different colors to see the groups clearly, as you can see below:

[image]